# How to create a function where the user picks rows of a data frame based on a character vector

Tags: r, function, subset

I need to create a function (using the function() code) that will let a user enter their name as a character in a vector called `myname`. The function will create a data frame that is a subset of `babynames`, including only rows where `name` is in `myname`.

I tried writing the code, but the part I can't seem to understand is: how does the function know that `myname` will be found in the `names` column of the data frame? I also thought I made the subset correctly but when I run it, it has 0 observations.

Here is some sample data

[image: I don't know how to add sample data so here's a picture of the top of the table]

```
nametrend <- function(myname) {
    bn <- subset(babynames, name == myname, select = c("year", "n")) plot(x = bn$year, y = bn$n, main = myname, col = 'purple')
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: And show how you are calling the function. And perhaps see and heed the *Warning* in the `?subset` documentation: *This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like `[`, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences.*"

Comment: Okay, I added a picture of the first couple rows of the table. For example, I need the function to take all the rows with the name 'Mary' and plot the number of people with that name by year. I also just started learning R a couple weeks ago so I don't know that much about it or some of the words you are using lol. How would I subset it with [ ?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share sample data so it can by copy/pasted. `dput(droplevels(babynames[1:20, ]))` will give us the first 20 rows. Edit the output of that into your question.

Comment: And that also illustrates subsetting with `[`. `babynames[1:20, ]` is the first 20 rows. `babynames[babynames$name == "Mary", ]` is all the rows where the name is "Mary". `babynames[babynames$name == "Mary", c("year", "n")]` is the rows where name is Mary, selecting only the year and n columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use %in% like this

```
year <- 2000:2019
n <- round(rnorm(length(year), 0))
name <- c(rep("alex", 5), rep("ben", 10), rep("mary", 5))
babyname <- data.frame(year, n, name)

myname <- "alex"
bn <- babyname[babyname$name %in% myname, ]
bnl   
  year  n name
1 2000  0 alex
2 2001  1 alex
3 2002 -1 alex
4 2003  2 alex
5 2004 -1 alex
```

Inside your function and with multiple values as myname this would be

```
nametrend <- function(myname) {
bn <- babyname[babyname$name %in% myname, ]
bn$name <- droplevels(bn$name)
plot(x = bn$year, y = bn$n, main = myname, col = bn$name)
legend("topleft", legend= levels(bn$name), pch=16, col=unique(bn$name))
}

myname <- c("alex", "mary")

nametrend(myname)
```

Comment: This method seems to be working except how do I test this code? I tried just doing nametrend(Mary) but it doesn't seem to work. Am I supposed to put more information inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, it must be a character. So you must type "alex", for example

Comment: Omg it worked perfectly!!!!!! You're a godsend, thank you so much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking along the lines of something like

```
ask_for_names <- function(){
  name_1 <- readline(prompt = "Enter a name: ")
  name_1
  # Probably should add checks to make sure it is valid
  # e.g. as.character(name_1)
}

input_into_next_function <- ask_for_names()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about asking user their name if you want to make it interactive as,

```
 nametrend <- function(myname = readline("What is your name? ")) {
    bn <- subset(babynames, name == myname, select = c("year", "n")) 
    plot(x = bn$year, y = bn$n, main = myname, col = 'purple')
}
nametrend()
```